# Assign more than one value to a vector at the same time

Tags: r

I would like to know if it is possible to assign more than one value to a vector using only one statement. For example, suppose that I have a data frame made of 3 columns `name`, `age` and `sex` and I want to modify, let's say, row #40. Normally I would do something like this

```
 df[40,]$name <- 'Foo'
 df[40,]$age <- 75
```

However, I am wondering if it can be done in one statement (like Python multiple assignment). It's okay if it can be done using an external package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do

```
df[40, c("name", "age")] <- list("Foo", 75)
```

As long as the `name` column is not factor, it should be fine.

Comment: That did the job. Thanks.